# PHP decode of JSON doesn't work from the Google translate API

Tags: php

I'm trying to decode this JSON returned by Google Translation Service:

```
$r = '[[["Hola Mundo","Hello World",,,1]],,"en"]'
```

But when I do this:

```
echo json_decode($r);
```

it returns me null.

I got this manual maded for JS, just trying to made it with PHP

https://ctrlq.org/code/19909-google-translate-api

Comment: Are you using an officially documented Google API which is documented and guaranteed to return JSON? Well, no. And Google probably no likey that. So it doesn't actually return actual JSON...

Comment: Jaja, of course Google doesn't like it, just playing with the "API" from the tutorial. It seem to be the Chrome Browser particular API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify your issue,

JSON is a string (and in PHP should be quote encapsulated), in your code, you have not declared it as a string but an array, and just to be clear you can instantiate an array with a couple methods:

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray2 = [];
```

So to fix your issue; encapsulate your JSON string, replace `echo json_decode($r)` with `var_dump($r)` and voila

Eg

```
$r = '[[["Hola Mundo","Hello World",,,1]],,"en"]';
var_dump(json_decode($r));
```

**BUT** that is not valid JSON syntax (check on http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the ''; It seem to be an incorrect result from Google. Thanks!